# Why using self keyword when calling parent method from child method in Python?

Tags: python, oop, overriding, self

Why it's required to use self keyword as an argument when calling the parent method from the child method?

Let me give an example,

```py
class Account:

     def __init__(self,filepath):
         self.filepath = filepath
         with open(self.filepath,"r") as file:
              self.blanace = int(file.read())

     def withDraw(self,amount):
          self.blanace = self.blanace - amount
          self.commit()

     def deposite(self,amount):
          self.blanace = self.blanace + amount
          self.commit()


     def commit(self):
          with open(self.filepath,"w") as file:
               file.write(str(self.blanace))



class Checking(Account):

      def __init__(self,filepath):
           Account.__init__(sellf,filepath) ######## I'm asking about this line.
```

Regarding this code,

I understand that self is automatically passed to the class when declaring a new object, so,

I expect when I declare new object, python will set self = the declared object, so now the self keyword will be available in the "'**init**'" child method, so no need to write it manually again like

```py
Account.__init__(sellf,filepath) ######## I'm asking about this line.
```

Comment: When you call a method via `instance.methodname()`, the `instance` is passed to the method as a first argument. When you call a method via `classname.methodname()`, you're not telling it what instance you're talking about unless you pass it explicitly as an argument.

Comment: @khelwood : Most straightforward answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All instance methods are just `function`-valued class attributes. If you access the attribute via an instance, some behind-the-scenes "magic" (known as the descriptor protocol) takes care of changing `foo.bar()` to `type(foo).bar(foo)`. `__init__` itself is also just another instance method, albeit one you usually only call explicitly when overriding `__init__` in a child.

In your example, you are explicitly invoking the parent class's `__init__` method via the class, so you have to pass `self` explicitly (`self.__init__(filepath)` would result in infinite recursion).

One way to avoid this is to *not* refer to the parent class explicitly, but to let a proxy determine the "closest" parent for you.

```
 super().__init__(filepath)
```

There is some magic here: `super` with no arguments determines, with some help from the Python implementation, which class it statically occurs in (in this case, `Checking`) and passes that, along with `self`, as the implicit arguments to `super`. In Python 2, you always had to be explicit: `super(Checking, self).__init__(filepath)`. (In Python 3, you can still pass argument explicitly, because there are some use cases, though rare, for passing arguments other than the current static class and `self`. Most commonly, `super(SomeClass)` does *not* get `self` as an implicit second argument, and handles class-level proxying.)

---

Specifically, the `function` class defines a `__get__` method; if the result of an attribute lookup defines `__get__`, the return value of that method is returned instead of the attribute value itself. In other words,

```
foo.bar
```

becomes

```
foo.__dict__['bar'].__get__(foo, type(foo))
```

and that return value is an object of type `method`. Calling a `method` instance simply causes the original function to be called, with its first argument being the instance that `__get__` took as its first argument, and its remaining arguments are whatever other arguments were passed to the original method call.

Comment: I deleted my comment, you have shown it quite well, thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I would tally this one up to [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) -- specifically, the following statements:

1. Explicit is better than implicit.
2. Readability counts.
3. In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

... and so on.

It's the mantra of Python -- this, along with many other cases may seem redundant and overly simplistic, but being explicit is one of Python's key "goals." Perhaps another user can give more *explicit* examples, but in this case, I would say it makes sense to not have arguments be explicitly defined in one call, then vanish -- it might make things unclear when looking at a child function without also looking at its parent.